# We can't use TAB key or Left/Right Arow Key in close modal dialog in firefox and vscode on Kubuntu 19.04

Tags: firefox, plasma5, user-interface

system: Kubuntu 19.04
kde plasma version: 5.15.4
kde frameworks version: 5.56.0
Qt version: 5.12.2
kernel: 5.0.0-29-generic
os type: 64-bit

when you close one tab in kate text editor (CTRL+W) , you can realize which button has the focus, meaby with a blue color (kde applications) or with a dotted line on the button. You can use left/right arow or TAB.

**Kate text editor**

[image]

But in some applications (GTK+), is impossible to know so and left/right arrows or TAB doesn't work properly in these cases. For example in **Firefox** when you have more than one tab after close the app (ALT+F4).

[image]

Similar in **vscode**, when you close one tab (CTRL+W).

[image]

Is there a way to work around that behavior?
Is there a solution?, thanks in advance.

**Update 17-01-2020**
Operating System: KDE neon 5.17
KDE Plasma Version: 5.17.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.66.0
Qt Version: 5.13.2
Kernel Version: 5.0.0-37-generic
OS Type: 64-bit

vscode: 1.41.4

[image]

On vscode TAB key, Left/Right Arrows key, ALT+underline letter works well.

[image]

On Firefox only ALT key work but "close tabs" button never is colored, Arrows key doesn't work properly.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It should be a problem with plasma's theme.

In plasma's settings, go to “Appearance” → “Application Style” → “GNOME Application Style (GTK)”, and change the GTK2 and GTK3's theme, you may find a working theme.